# Autocad HATCH to polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, autocad, region

I have a erosion map and land use map in DWG files, made of regions (boundary) and hatches.

How to convert regions or hatches to polygons?

This is the picture of the map in DWG file.

[image]

Comment: Can you offer some test data?

Comment: this the link .dwg fail. you have in it the example of region and hatch that i want to export to .shp.

https://mega.nz/#!4hMwDbDJ!2d-DhU2OzIVTnCGGcX-AOZS7wpTOMW5IyWrxIE0_jeg

Answer (score 3):

Autocad Solution:

In autocad there is a command "_HATCHGENERATEBOUNDARY", select all hatches and apply this command. This will generate a polyline to all hatches than import/export polyline to polygon.

Regarding to regions.

1.Select all regions and apply explode command.

2.This will convert all regions to line.

3.Than if you have no acadmap apply comand "pedit"-polyline edit and chose multiple.

4.Than chose option "Join".

5.This will convert all lines to polylines.

Comment: this the link to .dwg fail. you have in it the example of region and hatch that i want to export to .shp. 

mega.nz/#!4hMwDbDJ!2d-DhU2OzIVTnCGGcX-AOZS7wpTOMW5IyWrxIE0_j‌​eg

Comment: first answer i dont know to perform.

second gives me polygons, but they overlap.

Comment: they overlap because hatches or boundaries have been overlapped too, so after converting to polyline you can perform Drawing Cleanup at autocad or convert overlapped feature to GIS than repar overlapping using QGIS or other GIS software.

Comment: I opened your file using autocadmap. 1- Exploded all regions to line. 2- Applied drawing cleanup by choosing (1.break crossing, 2.delete duplicates, 3.snap clustered nodes,4. dissolve pseudonods, 5.break crossing), Lines to polylines. 3- Create polygon topology (Map drafting/ topology/ create topology). 4- Convert topology to polygon (polygon toolbar).

Comment: if you have no autocad map license than you should try to convert polylines to QGIS and edit there overlapping polygons.

Comment: http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20Map%203D%202010%20User%20Documentation/HTML%20Help/index.html?url=WS577DED0A95F53B408A6BF9656CAD6D4E.htm,topicNumber=d0e71485

Comment: http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20Map%203D%202010%20User%20Documentation/HTML%20Help/index.html?url=WS143A0F2DA58923429C73E4C1B9AB388F.htm,topicNumber=d0e85051

Comment: this is not working :(

Comment: maybe to convert hatch to polygon?

Comment: apply careful listed steps, and all will work. i dont know if there is a command to convert hatch to polygon, if so go ahead.

Comment: i found the solution :DDDD
http://cad2shape.sharewarejunction.com/#download

Comment: HATCHGENERATEBOUNDARY+MAPPOLYLINETOPOLYGON generates polygons into one layer. Is there a way that can generate polygons belonging to the original hatched layers?

Comment: @user12949097, a bit late but you can try to export into shapefile (within layer attribute), then using QGIS convert polylines to polygon. While importing back to cad there is an option to use a field as a layer (choose the previos exported field, which normally should has the name Layer).

Answer (score 1):

Type in Autocad mapexport, choose the online option, select the features required and export to SHAPEFILE in QGIS utlize SAGA complement the Process panel for converting line polygon.

Comment: this the link to .dwg fail. you have in it the example of region and hatch that i want to export to .shp. 

mega.nz/#!4hMwDbDJ!2d-DhU2OzIVTnCGGcX-AOZS7wpTOMW5IyWrxIE0_j‌​eg

Comment: I tried this way you answerd, and it's not working. i get polygons but they overlap.

Comment: i found the solution :DDDD cad2shape.sharewarejunction.com/#download